# Ошибка Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given в запросе

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Помогите исправить ошибку в запросе:

> Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in   D:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\train2\second.php on line 29
>   ERROR QUERRY

index.php

```
<form action="second.php" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
    <label for="first_name">first name</label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name"> <br>
    <label for="first_name">last_name</label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name"> <br>
    <label for="first_name">bio</label>
    <input type="text" name="bio"> <br>
    <label for="first_name">email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email"> <br>
    <label for="first_name">facebook_url</label>
    <input type="text" name="facebook_url"> <br>
    <label for="first_name">twitter_url</label>
    <input type="text" name="twitter_url"> <br>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="submit" name="ok">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

second.php

```
<?php 

require "db_connection.php";

$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$bio = $_POST['bio'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$facebook_url = $_POST['facebook_url'];
$twitter_url = $_POST['twitter_url'];

$show_tb = mysqli_query($connection, "SHOW TABLES");
$sel_tb = mysqli_query($connection, "USE TABLES my");

if ($sel_tb) {
    mysqli_error();
}else{
    echo "<br> okkkkkkkkkkk <br>";
}
$qq = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM my");
if (!$qq) {
    echo "noooooo" . mysqli_query();
}else{
    echo "select good";
}
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO my(first_name, last_name, bio, email, facebook_url, twitter_url) VALUES ($first_name, $last_name, $bio, $email, $facebook_url, $twitter_url)");

if (!$query) {
    die("ERROR QUERRY" . mysqli_error());
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query)) {
echo "You'e use  {$row[0]}";
}

mysqli_close($connection);
 ?>
```

Подключение к БД есть. Только не могу сделать запрос в БД посредством ввода информации в инпут.

Comment: Используйте подготовленные запросы (prepared statements) и таких проблем не будет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given

Не хватает параметра в вызове функции. Вы не указали идентификатор соединения

> Процедурный стиль
>
> `string mysqli_error ( mysqli $link )`
>
> Возвращает сообщение об ошибке последнего вызова функции MySQLi,
>   который может успешно выполниться или провалиться.
>
> Список параметров:
>
> `link` Только для процедурного стиля: Идентификатор соединения, полученный с помощью mysqli_connect() или mysqli_init()

Если используете процедурный стиль, то вам надо указывать

```
mysqli_error($connection);
```

Если объектно-ориентированный, то:

```
$connection->mysqli_error();
```

Кстати

```
echo "noooooo" . mysqli_query();
```

вызовет ту же ошибку